# Buttons bugging on lauch and the label inside them disappearing when I used Commands

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

Im using some commands to put my buttons more dynamic and Im having some bugs. One of them is when I lauch my program the style of my buttons bug and looks like this:

[image: sample]

Instead of this:

[image: correct]

Only appear me the correct style when the code-behind of the command is called.

The second problem is that my Text isn't appearing.

My buttons code:

```
<telerikPrimitives:RadBorder x:Name="BorderMinus" BorderColor="#3F3C42" BorderThickness="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Margin="3,2,2,2">
   <Button x:Name="QntMinus" Text="-" Padding="0" Command="{Binding DecrementQuantityCommand, Source={x:Reference ExtendedContentView}}" Margin="-1" BackgroundColor="{Binding DecrementQuantityCommandEnabled, Source={x:Reference ExtendedContentView}, Converter={StaticResource Batata}, ConverterParameter={x:Reference Name=MainColorGrid2}}"/>
</telerikPrimitives:RadBorder>

<Label x:Name="QntLabel" Text="{Binding SelectedSize.Quantity, Source={x:Reference ExtendedContentView}}" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="White" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>

<telerikPrimitives:RadBorder x:Name="BorderPlus" BorderColor="#FF8A00" BorderThickness="1" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Margin="2,2,3,2">
   <Button x:Name="QntPlus" Text="+" Padding="0" Command="{Binding IncrementQuantityCommand, Source={x:Reference ExtendedContentView}}" Margin="-1" BackgroundColor="{Binding IncrementQuantityCommandEnabled, Source={x:Reference ExtendedContentView}, Converter={StaticResource Batata}, ConverterParameter={x:Reference Name=MainColorGrid2}}"/>
</telerikPrimitives:RadBorder>
```

And the coverter that Im using is implemented in xaml like this:

```
<ContentView.Resources>
   <ResourceDictionary>
      <local:IsActiveToColorConverter x:Key="Batata" />
   </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentView.Resources>
```

My code-behind:

```
public partial class ExtendedButton : ContentView
{
   public bool IncrementQuantityCommandEnabled { get; set; }
   public bool DecrementQuantityCommandEnabled { get; set; }
   public ICommand IncrementQuantityCommand { get; set; }
   public ICommand DecrementQuantityCommand { get; set; }

   public void IncrementQuantity()
   {           
      if (SelectedSize.IncrementQuantity())
      {
         if (SelectedSize.Quantity == 10)
         {
            IncrementQuantityCommandEnabled = false;
         }

         DecrementQuantityCommandEnabled = true;
      }            
   }

   public void DecrementQuantity()
   {
      if (SelectedSize.DecrementQuantity())
      {
         if (SelectedSize.Quantity == 1)
         {
            DecrementQuantityCommandEnabled = false;
         }

         IncrementQuantityCommandEnabled = true;
      }
   }

   public ExtendedButton()
   {
      InitializeComponent();

      IncrementQuantityCommandEnabled = true;
      DecrementQuantityCommandEnabled = true;
      IncrementQuantityCommand = new Command(() => IncrementQuantity(), () => IncrementQuantityCommandEnabled);
      DecrementQuantityCommand = new Command(() => DecrementQuantity(), () => DecrementQuantityCommandEnabled);
   }
}

public class IsActiveToColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
   public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      Grid grid = parameter as Grid;
      Color mainColorDisabled = Color.Green;
      Color mainColor = Color.Pink;

      bool first = true;

      foreach (var item in grid.Children)
      {
         var label = item as Label;

         if (first)
         {
            mainColor = label.BackgroundColor;
            first = false;
         }
         else
         {
            mainColorDisabled = label.BackgroundColor;
         }
      }

      var isActive = (bool)value;

      if (isActive)
      {
         return mainColor;
      }
      else
      {
         return mainColorDisabled;
      }
   }

   public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the issue that you're facing but if it's an Android problem, you might want to try to fiddle with [Button Padding and Shadow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/android/button-padding-shadow)

Comment: @MikolajKieres Sorry for the delayed response. Should I set the two options that are in the link that you sent me to false?

Comment: You're probably more interested in padding than in shadow, so try setting it to true/false and see if it changes anything